# rb_class_new_instance raises "ArgumentError: wrong type" - why?

Tags: c, ruby-c-extension

From my Ruby C Extension I wanted to create a new `Geom::Vector3d` instance from the Google SketchUp Ruby API: https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/vector3d

My initial code was this:

```
static inline VALUE
vector_to_sketchup( Point3d vector )
{
  VALUE skp_vector, args[3];

  args[0] = rb_float_new( vector.x );
  args[1] = rb_float_new( vector.y );
  args[2] = rb_float_new( vector.z );

  skp_vector = rb_class_new_instance( 3, args, cVector3d );
}
```

This however raised an error:

```
Error: #<ArgumentError: wrong type - expected Sketchup::Vector3d>
```

Instead I had to call the ruby `new` method - like so:

```
static inline VALUE
vector_to_sketchup( Point3d vector )
{
  VALUE skp_vector;

  skp_vector = rb_funcall( cVector3d, sNew, 3,
    rb_float_new( vector.x ),
    rb_float_new( vector.y ),
    rb_float_new( vector.z )
  );

  return skp_vector;
}
```

I ran into the same problem with [Geom::Point3d](https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/point3d) and [Sketchup::Color](https://developers.google.com/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/color).

`rb_class_new_instance` is the preferred way to create a new instance in Ruby C, right?
Anyone got any idea why I needed to call `new`? Some oddity with how the class was defined in SketchUp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating with the developers of Google SketchUp I have found the cause of this.

SketchUp makes use of `Data_Wrap_Struct` to link their C classes with the Ruby classes. But they use an old method of allocating the data - which is within the `#new` method.

In Ruby 1.8 you use `rb_define_alloc_func()` to do the allocation and you never mess around with `#new`. Ruby (1.6 and 1.8) defines `#new` to call `rb_class_new_instance()`.

Since I used `rb_class_new_instance()` on SketchUp's old style classes the objects where not created properly, the allocation function was bypassed and never triggered. The error I got came from SketchUp, not Ruby.

So the answer is, you can use `rb_class_new_instance()` to create new instances of classes provided they haven't overloaded the `#new` method to do any initializations. Before Ruby 1.6 this was common for Ruby C classes if they needed to allocate data, but as of 1.8 it *should* be done with `rb_define_alloc_func()`. (Matz says so here: https://web.archive.org/web/20131003102349/http://www.justskins.com/forums/the-new-allocation-scheme-132572.html#post437362 )

You can see the differences between Ruby 1.6 style and 1.8 style in this post: https://web.archive.org/web/20131003102349/http://www.justskins.com/forums/the-new-allocation-scheme-132572.html#post444948